# How can i use xaxis_date() with barh()?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, bar-chart

in the code below, bdate and edate are both datetime.datetime() objects:

```
pylab.barh(ypos, edate - bdate, left=bdate, height=TRMWidth )
```

but this throws an AttributeError way down in dates.py._to_ordinalf() :

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1926, in barh
>       ret = ax.barh(bottom, width, height, left, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4774, in barh
>       orientation='horizontal', **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4624, in bar
>       width = self.convert_xunits( width )
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 147, in convert_xunits
>       return ax.xaxis.convert_units(x)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1312, in convert_units
>       ret =  self.converter.convert(x, self.units, self)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1125, in convert
>       return date2num(value)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 260, in date2num
>       else: return np.asarray([_to_ordinalf(val) for val in d])
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 189, in _to_ordinalf
>       base =  float(dt.toordinal())
>
> AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

i thought it'd be great if i could just shove datetimes at xaxis and have it
work out the details; not so much.  any suggestions as to how to make dates agreaable to xaxis?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What's happening is that matplotlib doesn't actually use datetime objects for plotting.

Dates are first converted into an internal floating point format. The conversion isn't set up to handle timedeltas (which is arguably an oversight).

You can basically do exactly what you wanted, you just need to explictly convert the dates to matplotlib's internal format first, and then call `ax.xaxis_date()`.

As a quick example (Most of this is generating data to plot...):

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def drange(start, end, interval=dt.timedelta(days=1)):
    output = []
    while start <= end:
        output.append(start)
        start += interval
    return output

# Generate a series of dates for plotting...
edate = drange(dt.datetime(2012, 2, 1), dt.datetime(2012, 6, 15), 
                      dt.timedelta(days=5))
bdate = drange(dt.datetime(2012, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2012, 5, 15), 
                      dt.timedelta(days=5))

# Now convert them to matplotlib's internal format...
edate, bdate = [mdates.date2num(item) for item in (edate, bdate)]

ypos = range(len(edate))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the data
ax.barh(ypos, edate - bdate, left=bdate, height=0.8, align='center')
ax.axis('tight')

# We need to tell matplotlib that these are dates...
ax.xaxis_date()

plt.show()
```

[image]