# How to get gantt plot using matplotlib for task with start time and end time upto millisecs

Tags: python, matplotlib, gantt-chart

I am having data in a dataframe for each task with start time, end time and status.
I want to draw a gantt chart for this. I tried following other question on stackoverflow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367690/how-to-get-gantt-plot-using-matplotlib)) but they used numerical values so not able to use them. Below is the code.

```
import pandas as pd   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
data = [['A', '2019-06-27 18:33:58.033', '2019-06-27 19:54:04.658', 'Success'], ['B', '2019-06-27 19:54:04.957', '2019-06-27 19:54:14.570', 'Success'], ['B', '2019-06-27 19:54:04.963', '2019-06-27 19:54:19.928', 'Failed']]
#Converting List to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Task', 'Start Time', 'End Time', 'Status']) 
#Calculating the Time Difference
df['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Time']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])

color = {"Success":"turquoise", "Failed":"crimson"}
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,3))
labels=[]

for i, task in enumerate(df.groupby("Task")):
    labels.append(task[0])
    for r in task[1].groupby("Status"):
        data = r[1][["Start Time", "Duration"]]
        ax.broken_barh(data.values, (i-0.4,0.8), color=color[r[0]] )

ax.set_yticks(range(len(labels)))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels) 
ax.set_xlabel("time [ms]")
plt.tight_layout()       
plt.show()
```

Its not showing correct graph, may be due to time format. The above code works well if I use decimal numbers in place of time. Any help here.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042290/how-can-i-use-xaxis-date-with-barh, broken_barh expect numbers hence you can do the same to change your datetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to draw the graph using time in matplotlib, however not able to color bars differently for success and failure. Solution with this feature is welcomed.

```
import pandas as pd    
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [['A', '2019-06-27 18:33:58.033', '2019-06-27 19:54:04.658', 'Success'], ['B', '2019-06-27 19:54:04.957', '2019-06-27 19:58:14.570', 'Success'], ['C', '2019-06-27 19:54:04.963', '2019-06-27 19:54:19.928', 'Failed']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Task', 'Start_Time', 'End_Time', 'Status']) 

df_phase = df
df_phase['Start_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_phase['Start_Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df_phase['End_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_phase['End_Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

#Convert DF columns into lists
sdate = df_phase['Start_Time'].tolist()
edate = df_phase['End_Time'].tolist()
tasks = df_phase['Task'].tolist()

#Convert time to Matplotlib number format
edate, sdate = [dates.date2num(item) for item in (edate, sdate)]
time_diff = edate - sdate
ypos = range(len(tasks))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(ypos, time_diff, left=sdate, height=0.8, align='center', color='blue',edgecolor='black')
plt.yticks(ypos, tasks)
ax.axis('tight')

# We need to tell matplotlib that these are dates...
ax.xaxis_date()
plt.show()
```

Output Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

seems late though here is your code with slightly merged with Rishi's -

```
import pandas as pd   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
data = [['A', '2019-06-27 18:33:58.033', '2019-06-27 19:54:04.658', 'Success'], ['B', '2019-06-27 19:54:04.957', '2019-06-27 19:54:14.570', 'Success'], ['C', '2019-06-27 19:54:04.963', '2019-06-27 20:54:19.928', 'Failed']]
#Converting List to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Task', 'Start_Time', 'End_Time', 'Status']) 
#Calculating the Time Difference
#df['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Time']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
df_phase = df
df_phase['Start_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_phase['Start_Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df_phase['End_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_phase['End_Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

color = {"Success":"turquoise", "Failed":"crimson"}
#Convert DF columns into lists
sdate = df_phase['Start_Time'].tolist()
edate = df_phase['End_Time'].tolist()
tasks = df_phase['Task'].tolist()
#Convert time to Matplotlib number format
edate, sdate = [dates.date2num(item) for item in (edate, sdate)]
df_phase['Duration']=edate - sdate
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,3))
labels=[]

for i, task in enumerate(df_phase.groupby("Task")):
    labels.append(task[0])
    for r in task[1].groupby("Status"):
        data = r[1][["Start_Time", "Duration"]]
        ax.broken_barh(data.values, (i-0.4,0.8), color=color[r[0]] )

ax.set_yticks(range(len(labels)))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels) 
ax.set_xlabel("time [ms]")
plt.tight_layout()       
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]